# Mount an Azure Blog to a(n) Ubuntu System

Tags: mount, azure

I've created a storage account, in which there is a blob service, in which there is a container, in which there are some page blobs.

One of these page blobs is a 500GB permanent storage device that was mounted to a VM I host (also with Azure), however, when I closed down/started up the VM it was attached to, the mount was lost.

```
SR /dev :) > df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3563020        8   3563012   1% /dev
tmpfs             713580      424    713156   1% /run
/dev/sda1       30202916 11112784  17824100  39% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3567896        0   3567896   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
none                  64        0        64   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
/dev/sdb1      103079200    61048  97758992   1% /mnt
```

It no longer seems to appear in /dev and where it was mounted `/home/server` appears empty.  Is there a way to re-mount it to the file system using the Azure CLI or other method?

Comment: Note, I initially created the device through the Azure CLI, not via the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify the /etc/fstab file after mounting your drive? If not, the mount drive will only be availabe this time. After reboot, you need to mount it again.

Microsoft has already give the method to modify the fstab file, you can find the followings in the link below

> To ensure the drive is re-mounted automatically after a reboot it must
>   be added to the /etc/fstab file. In addition, it is highly recommended
>   that the UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) is used in /etc/fstab to
>   refer to the drive rather than just the device name

[How to Attach a Data Disk to a Linux Virtual Machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-attach-disk/)

Comment: Aha, I knew I was being stupid there!  My temporary solution was to remove/add the disk every single time I rebooted, which was certainly not a great solution.  Thanks for the answer, and welcome to superuser.com :D